# Sending JMETER request to IP address error

Tags: http, jmeter, ip

I am running my JMETER test on a windows machine and want to send the request to another IP address.

In JMETER, Http request under Advanced option, I selected 'IP/Hostname' and added the IP address.
I also have added the target IP to the 'Advanced TCP/IP setting' in my machine but still getting this error:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.bind(Unknown Source)
at
```

org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:832)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:570)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Is anyone can help how to resolve the issue, and what might be causing this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per [BindException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/BindException.html) description:

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to bind a socket to a local address and port. Typically, the port is in use, or the requested **local address could not be assigned**.

What you're doing is changing the **source IP address** (aka [IP spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter)), this technique substitutes your IP address with another one (or alias) allowing JMeter to simulate requests coming from different IP addresses as by default it will use only one IP

If you want to send a request to an IP address - you don't need to change anything in JMeter or operating system configuration, just put the IP address to "Server Name or IP" field of the HTTP Request sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)) and that would be it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. What I actually want to achieve is to change the source IP address to simulate requests coming from another IP address. Say I'm using Dev URL's but I would like to send the request to QA and Pre-prod gateway IP's. How can I do this. I tried the IP spoofing and that's the error I'm getting. Thanks for the help.